# Can the New Angeles Sol prevent a current from being trashed if an agenda was stolen?

Tags: android-netrunner

The corp's id is the [New Angeles Sol: Your News](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09002) and some current is on the table.

Say runner steals an agenda. What is the order of abilities triggered? The current is trashed and then corp's id can bring it back, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[New Angeles Sol: Your News](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09002) allows you to *play* a **current** from HQ or Archives (paying its play cost), it does not *prevent* anything from happening.

After an agenda is scored or stolen, this ability triggers at which point you can play any **current** that is in Archives (or HQ). If a **current** was trashed as a part of scoring or stealing the agenda then the **current** will be in Archives and available to play.

This isn't quite the same as 'preventing' trashing, or making **current**s *untrashable* as they still need to be played and paid for.